# Есть ли JS-библиотека, которая позволит отобразить график рабочей смены человека?

Tags: php, javascript

Отрисовал график при помощи php (подгружается через ajax). Т.е есть td часов (00, ..., 23), в каждом td есть 60 div'ов (по 1 div'у для одной минуты). Зеленый - это перерыв, желтый - исключение (больничный и тд), синий - по плану. При наведении на зеленый или желтый элемент всплывает title с описанием (тип и время, например 12:45-13:00).

Проблема в том, что div'ов очень много и браузеры начинают подтормаживать, особенно IE.
Как это можно отрисовать по-другому? Есть ли библиотека для похожей задачи?

[image: График]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно отрисовывать не по 60 div'ов в каждом td, а лишь два или три (смотря что выполнялось), присвоить каждому ширину блока (в пикселях или процентах) в зависимости от того, сколько времени длилось действие. К примеру:

1 td = 120 пикселей,
1 минута: 120/60 = 2 пикселя,
человек 45 минут отдыхал, 15 минут работал,
1-ый блок будет 90 пикселей шириной с зеленым фоном, 2-ой 30 пикселей с синим фоном.

Comment: Спасибо, думаю этот способ самый оптимальный.

Comment: Реализовал, сначала сделал последовательность в массиве. И на основе переходящих значений последовательности выделил количество DIV'ов (если класс предыдущего значения не равен текущему, то разбить). Сейчас автоматом строятся DIV'ы. IE летает:)

Answer (score 4):

Это называется "Gantt chart". Разумеется не стоит делать много блоков. И есть множество библиотек, чтобы упростить решение. Выбор зависит от требуемой функциональности.

С помощью d3js можно так: https://github.com/dk8996/Gantt-Chart 
На Angular так: https://github.com/angular-gantt/angular-gantt
jQuery плагин: http://taitems.github.io/jQuery.Gantt/
Есть и специальная библиотека, Opensource, но с платной поддержкой:  https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/licenses.shtml

Answer (score 3):

Самое простое - загрубить данные и вместо поминутной точности сделать пятиминутную (сразу в 5 раз меньше дивов).

Самое правильное - научиться объединять смежные одинаковые дивы. Тогда их количество сразу уменьшится на пару порядков (судя по скриншоту).